# Perl EPIC Debugger in Eclipse Timing Out

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, activeperl, epic

I'm trying to use the EPIC debugger in Eclipse and it keeps timing out.  I'm running Windows 7, Eclipse 3.72, EPIC 0.5.46, Padwalker 1.94, and ActivePerl (64bit) 5.14.2.  I notice the last message before timeout is "launching delegate" and then the timeout dialog comes up.  I used it several weeks ago and it worked fine, and I don't see any updates to any software on my machine that would interact (e.g. java).  Is there something that expires in ActivePerl after 30 days?  Below is the output of the console.  I've checked my firewall and that's not the issue.  I've searched extensively and can't find an answer - thanks!

```
Unable to connect to remote host: 192.168.1.79:5000
Compilation failed in require.
 at C:/Users/sedwards/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Doug/bid_calc.pl line 0
    main::BEGIN() called at C:/Users/sedwards/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Doug/bid_calc.pl line 0
    eval {...} called at C:/Users/sedwards/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Doug/bid_calc.pl line 0
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
 at C:/Users/sedwards/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Doug/bid_calc.pl line 0
```

Comment: I am running a similar setup, and I have never encountered this message/ problem. Are you running everything on the same computer? 192.168.1.79? (By the way, due to some other problem. I have replaced ActivePerl by Strawberry Perl, (with Eclipse and EPIC), and it's running fine).

Comment: Thanks, Helen - this indirectly led to me figuring this out!  (and learning about Strawberry Perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had installed EPIC when I had my corporate VPN enabled, so I had to re-enable it to get it to work again.  Thanks, Helen - your comment about the IP address got me thinking... :-)